# Audio output, what type device do I need?

Tags: audio, audio-output, spdif

I've two different devices, a first one with s/pdif (optical) output and a second one with simple mini-jack 3.5 output. I want to 'mix' sound from both of them and make output for simple headphones. The actual problem is that I'm not sure how to get it done. I will try to describe couple solutions imho should work, but due to my poor experience I'm not sure what to choose. Help me please. So:

1. Behringer MX400 + s/pdif to analog converter + cable (3.5 - 6.35). I don't actually like the idea with this converter, and I prefer all-in-one solution.
2. External audio card, like NI Komplete 6 (this card has s/pdif input (but digital)). I'm not sure this will work without PC. And this card require USB power, maybe I can use USB 'travel adapter' instead?
3. DJ mixer. Sounds good but models with s/pdif inputs are extremely expensive and hard to find.
4. AV-receiver. I'm not sure will it work the way I want, but it has s/pdif inputs as well as analog LR inputs. It also has headphone output. But will it 'mix' sound from 2 inputs or I just have to choose one?
5. Or headphone amplifier like FiiO E17 with s/pdif and 3.5 input. But I'm not even sure will it output from 2 inputs simultaneously.

What solution can you suggest to me please.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: U want both play same sound at the same time?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: #5 won't work as the FiiO E17 doesn't have a mixer built in . . . you have to select the input (e.g. USB, optical, coax, aux).  #1 (s/pdif to analog, and then into a mixer as well as a second analog source) is probably your best bet if you can't use a PC for processing.

Comment: @ernie Ah I see... Thank you, seems like #1 is the really one and only affordable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're working with no PC, the setup is a bit problematic, and won't exactly be the cheapest either. Sound cards and stuff, even external ones, require a PC to work. You have a digital and an analog source, which means that you likely won't be able to mix them in one box (unless you get an expensive digital mixer with SPDIF input).

Personally, I would recommend a basic analog mixer (get them used for cheap), which would probably have a headphone out. You'll also need a DAC to convert the SPDIF to analog. Hook up your two sources to the mixer and you're good to go.

If you want audiophile quality, I would recommend a digital mixer or similar, or a higher-end analog setup with a better mixer and D/A. Once again, this is a rare situation and consumer equipment generally isnt up to this task.

Comment: Thank you, you make it clear for me. I think I will follow your advice. :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually i think the best option in the ones you mentioned is the last one. cause it'll definitely works and doesn't decrease sound quality.

but there is a free windows-base alternative which i suggest you to try first.

`Right Click` on volume icon on left bottom corner and choose `Playback devices`. then find `Stereo Mix` in the `Recording` tab (if not find, Right click on the white area and make all devices `Show`) and set it as `Default Device`.

Then open its `Properties` and check `Listen to this device` on `Listen` tab.

Then Choose your secondary Playback device in `Playback through this device` combo box. And press `OK`.

Then Activate your first playback device on `Playback` tab. and press `OK`.

now your system configured to listen to the 1st device like a microphone and play it back on the 2nd.

try that. hope it works!

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but the actual problem is that I need it to work without PC at all. =\

Comment: :) So in this case i think the last option would be the best choice.